# why nginx location returns 404 error?

Tags: nginx

Here is my /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:

```
server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        location /test{
                root /var/www/test;
                index index.html index.htm;
        }
```

When I type in: http://localhost:8080/ : I got the nginx welcome page : good

When I type in http://localhost:8080/test : I got a 404 error
(I created index.html and index.htm inside /var/www/test)

PS I did reload with :

```
/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -s reload
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `/test` to root directive. You need just indicate `/var/www`

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /test {
        root /var/www;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }
```

Comment: Of course I did reload. Can you tell me more about rights and owner ?

Comment: the NGinx server is running with which user ?

Comment: Nginx running with root user. nginx seems ok: when I change port 8080 to 8089, then I need to go to lcoalhost:8089. Strange is: when I do comment the directive "location /", I still can go to the the / location

Comment: it looks like nginx ONLY routes the / . Whatever I put like location /zaza, going to /zaza will give me 404 error

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that, nginx searches for the folder that we added as location in the root we provided, location `\test` and root `/var/www/test` in this case. As `/test` is not in `/var/www/test` it's showing error. If used `/var/www` instead it will work fine as nginx uses root + location.

To confirm, you're facing the same issue check the nginx error log. If you haven't changed the log location then the following command will do the job.

```
sudo tail -n 20 /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

and if it shows a message like below ,you can confirm the issue is same.

```
[error] 7480#7480: *1 open() "/var/www/test/test" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: XXX.XXX.XX.XX, server: , request: "GET /app HTTP/1.1", host: "XX.XX.XXX.XX"
```

to resolve this issue change the code as below,

```
server {

    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /test {
        root /var/www;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }
```

after the changes, restart the nginx service

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```